# Does Syndra's Scatter the Weak damage scale with spheres?

Tags: league-of-legends

Syndra's Scatter the Weak does a number of things that are a little hard to understand:

> (Active): Knocks enemies and Dark Spheres back, dealing magic damage
>   to them and any enemies they collide with. The distance of the
>   knockback increases depending on how close the affected units are to
>   Syndra upon cast. Dark Spheres that are knocked back also stun all
>   enemies in their path for 1.5 seconds ([source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Syndra_the_Dark_Sovereign)).

It's clear that enemies will take damage and also damage those who they collide with. It's also clear that anyone who has a sphere pushed through them will be stunned.

However, it sort of suggests that when spheres go through an enemy they deal damage. Does this damage scale with the number of spheres? Or is damage not dealt at all by the spheres, and they only stun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why they would do damage, and my experience playing against her is that they stun but don't damage when that ability is used.  The ability itself is the damager and they're just a way to manipulate the balls themselves to some end.  All of her other abilities have some damage attached to the balls if they are doing damage themselves in the description.

> (Active): Conjures a Dark Sphere at a target location, dealing magic damage. The sphere lasts for up to 6 seconds and can be manipulated by Syndra's other abilities.
>   Transcendent Bonus: Deals 15% bonus damage against Champions.
>   Cooldown: 4 seconds

Damages at the summon location

> (Active): Throws the grasped Dark Sphere or enemy at a target area. Enemies struck take magic damage and are slowed for 1.5 second.

Explicitly states how the ball damages

> (Active): Draws upon Syndra's full cataclysmic power, harnessing all Dark Spheres to deal magic damage to her target per sphere. Unleashed Power will use the three spheres that orbit Syndra, ensuring a minimum damage. 
>   All Dark Spheres remain on the ground for 6 seconds after Unleashed Power is used.

Explicit as well with how the balls act.

So it can be assumed that they're being explicit with the Scatter the Weak, if the balls did damage, they'd state it did some damage.

Comment: If you could add some pictures of a video testing it that would be even more convincing, but it makes sense that it doesn't do damage for the ball passing through them since that damage number isn't described anywhere. It would be very confusing if it did damage equal to her Q.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. The damage the spheres do when hit by STW is scaled by STW. I've tested this before, and the spheres definitely do damage and kill things when under normal circumstances they shouldn't.